# Google ads script sendEmail method generating incomplete csv

Tags: google-apps-script, google-ads-script

A script that was previously working (using the sendEmail method of MailApp to email an attached csv) is now getting truncated about 300 rows short of what should be in the complete file, and is even getting cut mid-cell at about the same row every time. Sometimes, copy/pasting the code into a new script and manually running will work, but often it still does not.

The report is <400KB and only needs like 3,100 rows, but is only containing about 2,8600.5 (truncated mid-row, mid-cell).

Has anyone experienced this or have any tips?

Comment: When I have these sort of problems it's almost always an inconsistency in the data.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.